# Compass + Blueprint non semantic classes

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass, blueprint-css

I've been using compass with blueprint for a while now and one thing I can't figure out is why it generates all the basic blueprint css classes. Like these:

```
#container .span-3 { width: 110px; }
#container .span-4 { width: 150px; }
```

I specify `--using blueprint/semantic` when creating the compass project, and no I don't have `@include blueprint` anywhere in my source. Why are these classes being generated and how do I get compass not to include them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem but I can't.  Here's what I did and what I got:

```
compass create my_project --using blueprint/semantic
```

The generated screen.scss file seems to want you to `@import "blueprint"`, as it contains the following lines initially:

```
// Import all the default blueprint modules so that we can access their mixins.
@import "blueprint";
```

The generated screen.css file does not contain `.span-x` anywhere, and the only place `#container` appears is in `body.two-col #container {`.

I modified the screen.scss file and recompiled.  No change -- no non-semantic classes showed up in screen.css.

Hope this helps...

(Tested with Compass version 0.11.5, Ruby 1.8.7, FreeBSD 8.2)